# Magic links for Stack Overflow in Japanese and Russian

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, magic-links

We have the magic link [pt.so] which expands to [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) in comments and chat. However, two other languages are less fortunate:

1. [ja.so] does not work in chat
2. In comments, [ja.so] becomes [Stack Overflow in Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), which does not agree with the official name of the site: スタック・オーバーフロー
3. [ru.so] work neither in chat nor in comments.

Comment: You're right; I'm investigating (interestingly, ru.so and ja.so *are* listed as lookups on chat; I'm finding out why it isn't working...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, right on all counts. Chat should be fixed by the time you read this; expansion on SO/SE sites will be fixed in the next build.