# Magic link for Stack Overflow in Spanish

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, chat, magic-links

Unlike other localized SO sites, which have magic links [pt.so], [ja.so], and [ru.so], Spanish Stack Overflow does not seem to have one: I tried [es.so] and [sp.so] to no avail, either in chat or comments.

---

Context: such shortcuts were implemented for other lang-SO sites after bug reports

- [Missing Magic Link for Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224732).
- [Magic links for Stack Overflow in Japanese and Russian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261619)

Comment: I guess this is more a [feature-request] than a [bug].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've gone ahead and added a `[es.so]` magic link - it will be with you in the next build out (rev: rev 2016.8.11.3879).

Comment: Uhms, [es.so] does not work in [this comment in Spanish L&U](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13454/rollback-in-spanish?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment25710_13454).

Comment: @Oded [es.so] is still not working in rev 2016.8.30.3937. There is also a cross site duplicate for this question in http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/191/127

Comment: @fedorqui & @Mariano  `[es.so]` now works.

Comment: It works in comments, but not in chat. This report was about both chat and comments and is now marked completed. Should I post again about chat specifically?

Comment: Did magic links ever work in chat, @zaq?

Comment: Don't know if `[es.so]` ever worked in chat, but the other [lang.so] links do: [example](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5172831#5172831)

Comment: Oded & @zaq I have tried `[es.so]` in chat before Aug 11, before the Aug 31 fix, and after, and it has never worked in chat. I'm sorry I can't seem to find an example, but I'm positive... I simply never found the need to use it, because I only chat in [es.so], so I just use `[main]`.

Comment: @zaq - fixed chat.

Comment: It is missing: `[meta.ja.so]`.

Comment: @ArtEze - none of those (for all language sites) exist. Either in chat or comments. I don't expect they will be implemented any time soon.